# split of equation in Latex

Tags: equations, split

somebody help me:
I have a equation as follow, but in Latex has error:

```
\begin{equation}
    \begin{split}
        {\mathcal{F}}_{Q,{\textrm{$\omega$}}_{\mathrm{b\ }}}&=\{\{t^2(1-\frac{1}{{({\textrm{$\Omega$}}^2_{\mathrm{R1}}+{\textrm{$\Omega$}}^2_{\mathrm{R2}})}^4}{({({\textrm{$\Omega$}}^2_{\mathrm{R1}}+{\textrm{$\Omega$}}^2_{\mathrm{R2}})}^2\\‎
            &+4\mathrm{cos}[\textrm{$\alpha$}]\mathrm{sin}[\textrm{$\theta$}]{\mathrm{Sin}}^2[\frac{1}{4}t\sqrt{{\textrm{$\Omega$}}^2_{\mathrm{R1}}+{\textrm{$\Omega$}}^2_{\mathrm{R2}}}]{\textrm{$\Omega$}}_{\mathrm{R1}}{\textrm{$\Omega$}}_{\mathrm{R2}}(\mathrm{cos}[\frac{1}{2}t\sqrt{{\textrm{$\Omega$}}^2_{\mathrm{R1}}+{\textrm{$\Omega$}}^2_{\mathrm{R2}}}]{\textrm{$\Omega$}}^2_{\mathrm{R1}}+{\textrm{$\Omega$}}^2_{\mathrm{R2}})\\‎
            &-({\textrm{$\Omega$}}^2_{\mathrm{R1}}+{\textrm{$\Omega$}}^2_{\mathrm{R2}})({\mathrm{cos}}^2[\frac{1}{2}t\sqrt{{\textrm{$\Omega$}}^2_{\mathrm{R1}}+{\textrm{$\Omega$}}^2_{\mathrm{R2}}}]{\textrm{$\Omega$}}^2_{\mathrm{R1}}+{\textrm{$\Omega$}}^2_{\mathrm{R2}})-\mathrm{cos}[\textrm{$\theta$}]((-1+4\mathrm{cos}[\frac{1}{2}t\sqrt{{\textrm{$\Omega$}}^2_{\mathrm{R1}}+{\textrm{$\Omega$}}^2_{\mathrm{R2}}}]){\textrm{$\Omega$}}^2_{\mathrm{R1}}{\textrm{$\Omega$}}^2_{\mathrm{R2}}\\‎
            &+{\textrm{$\Omega$}}^4_{\mathrm{R2}}+{\mathrm{cos}}^2[\frac{1}{2}t\sqrt{{\mathrm{\textrm{$\Omega$}}\mathrm{2}}^2+{\textrm{$\Omega$}}^2_{\mathrm{R1}}}]({\textrm{$\Omega$}}^4_{\mathrm{R1}}-{\textrm{$\Omega$}}^2_{\mathrm{R1}}{\textrm{$\Omega$}}^2_{\mathrm{R2}})))}^2)\}\}
    \end{split}
\end{equation}
```

Comment: Welcome to TSE. Please edit your question and add to it a Minimal Working Example.

Comment: You have far too much `\mathrm` and `\textrm`.  Let TeX typeset the math for you.

Comment: Most of the braces aren't necessary, and the critical error seems to be a "missing `}`" in the first line.  `\mathcal`, `\textrm`, and `\mathrm` don't have to be "protected" unless they're in sub- or superscripts.  Also, as noted in another comment, `\textrm` isn't needed here at all.  Did you enter this yourself, or was it created by some other process?

Comment: Why `{\textrm{$\Omega$}}` when `\Omega` suffices? Note also that `\cos` is predefined for the cosine. Remove the unnecessary braces and probably you'll find the culprit. As it stands, the code is really hard to interpret.

Answer (score 3):

How about this?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
        {\mathcal{F}}_{Q,{\textrm{$\omega$}}_{\mathrm{b\ }}}&=\{\{t^2(1-\frac{1}{{({\textrm{$\Omega$}}^2_{\mathrm{R1}}+{\textrm{$\Omega$}}^2_{\mathrm{R2}})}^4}{({({\textrm{$\Omega$}}^2_{\mathrm{R1}}+{\textrm{$\Omega$}}^2_{\mathrm{R2}})}^2}\\
            &+4\mathrm{cos}[\textrm{$\alpha$}]\mathrm{sin}[\textrm{$\theta$}]{\mathrm{Sin}}^2[\frac{1}{4}t\sqrt{{\textrm{$\Omega$}}^2_{\mathrm{R1}}+{\textrm{$\Omega$}}^2_{\mathrm{R2}}}]{\textrm{$\Omega$}}_{\mathrm{R1}}{\textrm{$\Omega$}}_{\mathrm{R2}}(\mathrm{cos}[\frac{1}{2}t\sqrt{{\textrm{$\Omega$}}^2_{\mathrm{R1}}+{\textrm{$\Omega$}}^2_{\mathrm{R2}}}]{\textrm{$\Omega$}}^2_{\mathrm{R1}}+{\textrm{$\Omega$}}^2_{\mathrm{R2}})\\
            &-({\textrm{$\Omega$}}^2_{\mathrm{R1}}+{\textrm{$\Omega$}}^2_{\mathrm{R2}})({\mathrm{cos}}^2[\frac{1}{2}t\sqrt{{\textrm{$\Omega$}}^2_{\mathrm{R1}}+{\textrm{$\Omega$}}^2_{\mathrm{R2}}}]{\textrm{$\Omega$}}^2_{\mathrm{R1}}+{\textrm{$\Omega$}}^2_{\mathrm{R2}})-\mathrm{cos}[\textrm{$\theta$}]((-1+4\mathrm{cos}[\frac{1}{2}t\sqrt{{\textrm{$\Omega$}}^2_{\mathrm{R1}}+{\textrm{$\Omega$}}^2_{\mathrm{R2}}}]){\textrm{$\Omega$}}^2_{\mathrm{R1}}{\textrm{$\Omega$}}^2_{\mathrm{R2}}\\
            &+{\textrm{$\Omega$}}^4_{\mathrm{R2}}+{\mathrm{cos}}^2[\frac{1}{2}t\sqrt{{\mathrm{\textrm{$\Omega$}}\mathrm{2}}^2+{\textrm{$\Omega$}}^2_{\mathrm{R1}}}]({\textrm{$\Omega$}}^4_{\mathrm{R1}}-{\textrm{$\Omega$}}^2_{\mathrm{R1}}{\textrm{$\Omega$}}^2_{\mathrm{R2}})))^2)\}\}
\end{split}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: No, no, no write equation on the such a way!

Comment: Thank you very much ,modnar, you solved my problem.

Comment: @seyed, you are welcome.

Comment: At the least, could you say what the difference is?  I'm not seeing what you've changed.  And there's a lot that should have changed but didn't.

Comment: You would do readers a real service if you recommended replacing code monstrosities such as `{\textrm{$\omega$}}`, `{\textrm{$\Omega$}}`, and many similar terms with `\omega`, `\Omega`, etc. Moreover, 2 of the 4 rows protrude grossly into the right-hand margin; any suggestion on hiring rectifying the problems?

Answer (score 0):

- In your code fragment is very easy go to lost. It is write against what the LaTeX is intendent...
- For (re)write your equation correctly, you need to show the image of desired equation.
- I try to clean-up first two lines, where I consider all comments below your question, but I'm not sure, if result is as you like to have:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
    \begin{split}
\mathcal{F}_{Q,\omega_\mathrm{b}}
    & = \biggl\{\biggl\{
        t^2\left(1-\frac{1}{\Omega^2_\mathrm{R1} + \Omega^2_{\mathrm{R2}^4}}\right)\Omega^2_\mathrm{R1} + 
        \Omega^2_{\mathrm{R2}^2}                    \\
    & + 4\cos\alpha\sin\theta \sin^2\left[\frac{1}{4} t\sqrt{\Omega^2_\mathrm{R1} + \Omega^2_\mathrm{R2}}\right]
        \Omega_\mathrm{R1}\Omega_\mathrm{R2}\cos\left[\frac{1}{2}t\sqrt{\Omega^2_\mathrm{R1}\Omega^2_\mathrm{R2}}\right]
        \Omega^2_\mathrm{R1} + \Omega^2_\mathrm{R2}  \\
    & \dots \biggr\}\biggr\}
     \end{split}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]